# Pass method dependency in MVC controller action Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can we pass dependency using unity, to a mvc controller action method ?

For example, if I have a POST action method with a dependency of **ITestRepository** type, which I would like to be injected through method injection ? I do not want the TestRepository to be instantiated withing this action method.

```
    public ActionResult SaveData(ITestRepository iRepoInstance)
    {
        var save = iRepoInstance.SaveData();
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Now why would you do that? If this is a POST, then this action method will receive data from the view. How do you want to post a repository from your view to your controller?

Comment: Why not inject it to the constructor?

Comment: @Serv, I don't know whether it is possible or not. The reason is to call the save method, i need to initialize the repository which implements it.

Comment: @Haim770, using constructor will always initialize or inject this dependency. I need to use this dependency in only one of the methods and not for all. So do not want it to get injected for methods which don't even need it.

Comment: You can easily write a `ITestRepositoryModelBinder` that will internally call  Unity to resolve `ITestRepository`, but that would be a total abuse of model-binding.

Comment: Any other better way ? Even using the property injection initializes/injects dependency, even when not required. Can i control that ?

Comment: Looking to do this, anyone found a solution? In short, I want to find the equivalent of injecting dependancies into mvc actions in .NET CORE using [FromServices] atrtibute - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?